# Existence of intermediate class without executing the parameterized base class constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-inheritance

My Code:

```
class Parent
{
public: Parent() { cout << "Default Parent" << endl; }
        Parent(int x) { cout << "Parameterized Parent" << endl; }
};
class Child1: virtual public Parent
{
public: Child1() :Parent(10) { cout << "Default Child1" << endl; }
};
class Child2: virtual public Parent
{
public: Child2() :Parent(10) { cout << "Default Child1" << endl; }
};
class GrandChild: public Child1, public Child2
{
public:
    GrandChild() { cout << "Default GrandChild" << endl; }
};
int main()
{
    GrandChild G;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
default Parent
default Child1
default Child2
default GrandChild
```

I know that here the most derived class calls the Parent class default constructor unless specified otherwise.

But why do the ChildX classes' parameterized Parent constructor calls never got executed? Without the ChildX classes the GrandChild class can not exist(?). Without the parameterized call the ChildX classes will not get created(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that here the most derived class calls the Parent class default constructor unless specified otherwise.

There's more to it than that. The most derived class **always** has the sole responsibility to initialize the virtual base classes. No exceptions!

If the most derived class's constructor doesn't specify a *mem-initializer* for the virtual base class, the virtual base class is default-constructed. It doesn't matter if the "intermediate" classes specify *mem-initializers* for the virtual base class. Those are simply ignored. They are **only** used when that class is the most derived class being constructed.

> A *mem-initializer* where the *mem-initializer-id* denotes a virtual base class is ignored during execution of a constructor of any class that is not the most derived class.

(C++14 standard, [class.base.init]/7)

Comment: Why don't the compilers give a warning regarding the ignored initialization?

Comment: @InQusitive It doesn't merit a warning; there's nothing obviously wrong with `Child1` and `Child2` wanting to initialize the virtual base one way when they're the most derived classes, and `GrandChild` wanting to do it differently.

Comment: @Brian There is one special case: in an abstract class, that initializer will never be executed.

Comment: @InQusitive Why would compiler give a warning?

Comment: @curiousguy: My VS sometimes gives warning when I have a statement which is a deadcode. Similarly, though it is not compulsory wouldn't it be nice to give a warning when a constructor is not executed.

Comment: @InQusitive "Dead code" is code that cannot never be executed. I agree that compilers could warn for ctor init that is never executed (inside an abstract class). I don't understand where you want a warning here. Do you also want a warning for using `abs(3.)` saying "warning: else branch of `if(x>0)` in `abs` not taken"? That would generate tons of warnings.